# Varialble re-initalized in multiple function calls

Tags: python, if-statement

I have to execute the following code wherein I will be calling the function main again and again.
so here as I need to use i = i+1, I need to declare and initialize i in the first place right, but when i call the main function it again defines i=0 and the whole purpose of i = i+1 is lost.
How can I solve this error?
I have given the condition just as an example.
Basically what I want is i should be initialized only once, inspite of how many number of times main is called.

```
def main():
    i = 0
    if 0<1:
        i = i+1
        y = i
```

Comment: You could use a global variable instead of a local one.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is a generator, rather than a function?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Comment: Can you give more context of how main is called and what y is for?

Comment: `0 < 1` is always True, I assume you always want to increment `i` and that the `if` is not needed?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this that don't involve globals. One is capture the value of `i` in a closure and return a new function that increments this. You will need to call the initial function once to get the returned function:

```
def main():
    i = 0
    def inner():
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        return i
    return inner

f = main()
f()
# 1
f()
# 2
```

You can also create a generator which is a more pythonic way to do this. The generator can be iterated over (although use caution since it iterates forever) or you can get a single value by passing it to `next()`:

```
def main():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

f = main()
next(f)
# 1
next(f)
# 2
```

You can also use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Answer (score 0):

So you haven't declared `i` as a global variable

Do something like this

```
global i
i = 0

def main():
if 0<1:
    global i
    i = i+1
    y = i
```

The reason behind this is because inside a function all the variables are local meaning they only exist inside the function while the function is called, so if you want a function to be able to change a variable for the whole code, you'll need to announce it as a global so python knows to change the value of it for the entire code

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I believe there is an easier way to do whatever it is you are doing

Comment: I would just avoid global variables and say `i` in an argument of `main`.

Comment: @Guimoute I agree but I don't understand what they're doing

Comment: Ahah fair enough, me neither :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to maintain state in a function call which is a good reason to convert it to a class.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def main(self):
        self.i += 1
        y = self.i

myclass = MyClass()
myclass.main()
myclass.main()
print(myclass.i)
```